# Why apples says NSFileHandle should not be used for Networking?

Tags: cocoa, sockets, tcp

Apple says [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/NetworkingOverview/CommonPitfalls/CommonPitfalls.html) that "Do Not Use NSSocketPort (OS X) or NSFileHandle for General Socket Communication".

Now I am trying hard to debug a socket disconnection issue.

Is there any performance issue if we use NSFileHandle ?

Are they discouraging usage of NSFileHandle only just because NSStream will helps in easy debugging ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Keep reading. The very document you link to explains why you shouldn't use NSFileHandle for networking:

> The NSFileHandle class circumvents the standard networking stack, which carries the following drawbacks:
>
> - Network connections made with NSFileHandle can be significantly less efficient than those made with the standard networking APIs.
> - Historically, using NSFileHandle for networking has resulted in either extremely poor performance or strange, hard-to-debug failures.
> - There is no straightforward way to use TLS authentication and encryption on connections made with NSFileHandle.
> - In iOS, NSFileHandle does not automatically activate the device’s cellular modem or on-demand VPN.
>
> Instead, use NSStream for remote connections and CFSocket for listening.